# save new and edited table values into core data

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

i searching for the best way to realize the following situation:

- i have data in my core data.
- i open the view controller with my tableview
- this tableview fetchts the core data values

but now the questions:
how should i solve the situations for new values and edited values:

Situation 1:
i can add a row with a button and fill it with data
Should i directly save it into core data, each time if a row is added?

Situation 2:
if i edited an exist row, should i directly update the exist record?

At the moment:
I request the records and save them into an array.
and all new changes will be apply to the array.
if the view will disappear, i delete all the requested records in core data and save the array value into core data. is this a good way? i think not ...

Comment: I would fetch all core data objects and pass them into tableViewController, that way it is much easier to handle with edits and changes etc. I would save new objects instantly and edit objects instantly in case your app is closed or crashes

Comment: "..and pass them into tableViewController..."; what do you mean with this statement? can you show me a little example please?

Comment: For example I have extra class for CoreData where I have functions to save delete fetch etc. In my VCs where I need those data I simply call these functions and they return me Core Data Objects into my array

Comment: okay i think this is the same way like i do this at the moment, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but you mentioned something about deleting the objects in core data. I don't delete any data from core data

Comment: but how do you solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151089/discussion-between-phyber-and-ghost108).

Comment: no solution until yet :(

Comment: Still waiting in the chat :)