# How to save and edited tableView cell row data to coredata and device contact?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview

I create contact viewController like this:
[image]

which when user click add phone, it will insert new blank phone row in tableView cell, which can be edited on phone number textfield and phone type name textfield (home, work, mobile and etc) beside it.

what I create is just like what contact UI from iOS like this :
[image]

which when you click uibarbuttonitem "Done" on top right navigation bar, it will save all phone tableView cell row data to coredata and device contact.

I already look for an answer, I found similar question one year ago but no correct answer on it :
[save new and edited table values into core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505979/save-new-and-edited-table-values-into-core-data)

I already make insert new row, showing row with contact phone from device contact, and delete row works correctly.

What I need are : when I type text on phone number textfield (or edit it if it already exist from device contact) and save edited text into coredata and device contact. Also when I edit phone type textfield, it will save edited text into coredata only.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: you want to save the edited value in coredata ?

Comment: @karthik, it is already solved. I already know the way to do it.

Comment: update your question with your answer. thar helps others too